# Error After Adding react-router-dom and Running npm run build in Next.js App, Error occurred prerendering page "/"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I recently added react-router-dom to my Next.js project, and everything works fine during development. However, when I run npm run build and deploy the application, I encounter the following error during the prerendering process:

```
Error
    at l (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:10:343)
    at C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:19:1632
    at C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:19:3359
    at k (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:19:3362)
    at nT (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46138)
    at nT (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59937)
    at nO (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:62795)
    at nI (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:65445)
    at nT (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:57207)
   Generating static pages (6/7)  [    ]                                                                                                                                                                                            

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error
    at l (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:10:343)
    at C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:19:1632
    at C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:19:3359
    at k (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\.next\server\app\page.js:19:3362)
    at nT (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46138)
    at nT (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59937)
    at nO (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:62795)
    at nI (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:65445)
    at nT (C:\Users\batin\OneDrive\Bureaublad\server-live\vercel\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:57207)
 ✓ Generating static pages (7/7)                                                                                                                                                                                                    

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /page: /
```

crimeData.tsx

```
'use client'
import {Crimes} from "@/types/db/Crimes";
import {WithId} from "mongodb";
import React, {ChangeEvent, useState} from "react";
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

interface FormProps {
    data: WithId<Crimes>[];
}

const Data: React.FC<FormProps> = ({data}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [municipality, setMunicipality] = useState<Crimes | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    const handleDropdown = (selectedOption: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const select = selectedOption.target.value
        const selectData = data.find((crime) => crime._id.toString() === select)

        if (selectData) {
            setMunicipality(selectData)
        }
    }

    const reload = () => {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    const handleButton = () => {
        try {
            if (municipality !== null) {
                navigate('crimes', {state: {municipality: municipality}});
                reload();
            } else {
                console.error(setError)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(setError)
        }
    }

    return (
        <main className={"flex flex-row"}>
            <div className={"dropdown flex flex-col items-start-4"}>
                <h2 className={'ml-5 font-bold'}>Crimineel dataset</h2>
                <select className={"other-drop p-4"} onChange={handleDropdown}>
                    {data.map((crimes) => (
                        <option key={crimes._id.toString()} value={crimes._id.toString()}>
                            {crimes.Title}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
                <button className={"btn btn-other"} onClick={handleButton}>
                    Resultaat
                </button>
            </div>
        </main>

    )
}

export default Data
```

page.tsx

```
import {getNeighborhoods} from '@/utlis/mongodb/neighborhood';
// import Data from './data'
import CrimeData from './crimeData'
import { getCrimes } from '@/utlis/mongodb/crimes';
import { getRiskscore } from '@/utlis/mongodb/riskscore';
// import User from './user'


export default async function Home() {
    try {
    const neighborhoodData = await getNeighborhoods()
    const data = await neighborhoodData.toArray()
    const crimesData = await getCrimes()
    const crimesD = await crimesData.toArray()
    const userData = await getRiskscore()
    const user = await userData.toArray()

    return (
        <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24 md:container md:mx-auto">
            <div className="homepage-div flex">
                <div className="home p-4">
                    <h1 className={"text-2xl font-bold mb-2"}>Politieoverlast</h1>
                    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
                    <p className={"text-gray-700"}>Welkom bij "politieoverlast," jouw online bron voor het verkennen van
                        maatschappelijke uitdagingen en het bevorderen van bewustwording. Onze missie is om een dieper
                        begrip te creëren van problemen die onze samenleving beïnvloeden, en we beginnen met twee
                        {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
                        cruciale datasets: alcoholoverlast en het mysterieuze "xxx."</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p className={"text-gray-700"}><b>Overlastscores voor Alcoholoverlast:</b> Dit is een probleem dat
                        vele gemeenschappen wereldwijd treft. Het overmatige gebruik van alcohol kan leiden tot ernstige
                        {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
                        gevolgen, waaronder gezondheidsproblemen, sociale conflicten en veiligheidsrisico's. Op
                        {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unescaped-entities */}
                        "politieoverlast" hebben we overlastscores verzameld en geanalyseerd om te laten zien welke
                        gemeenten het meest getroffen zijn door alcoholgerelateerde problemen. We presenteren deze
                        scores op een schaal van 1 tot 100 om de ernst van de situatie duidelijk te maken.</p>
                    <div className={"home-btns flex flex-row "}>
                        {/*<Data data={data}/>*/}
                        <CrimeData data={crimesD}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Gebruiker update</h2>
                        {/*<User data={user} />*/}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

and the routing logic seems to be causing issues during the build process. Any guidance on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't Next.js use it's own [routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating)?

Comment: Yes it does THX!

Comment: @Phil i have now a new problem how can i get the data to crimes/page.tsx i am now using inside the crimedata.tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'